# Unable to get variables from different files

Tags: php, mysqli

Im trying to get data from my database and echo it with a variable, but I have a problem with that. When I try to get my variables from different files it shows me this error:

> Undefined variable: con in.

Here some codes:

Code from functions.php:

```
include "authentication.php";

function GetData() {
$id = session_id();
$result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM accounts where id='$id'");
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3));
{ 
$email=$row3['email'];
$fullname=$row3['fullname'];
$usualname=$row3['usualname'];
$lastname=$row3['lastname'];
}
}
```

Code from authentication.php:

```
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = '***';
$DATABASE_PASS = '***';
$DATABASE_NAME = '***';

$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {

    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

This also happens when I try to get variables from other files..
Here you get some screenshots of the error from different files and different variables:

[image]

[image]

Both files are in the same directory called PHPscripts:

[image]

Comment: Where is the location of `authentication.php`? Is that file  included properly?

Comment: @Talk2Nit It's in the same folder as function.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem of scoping.

Remember that in PHP, variables in the `global` scope cannot be accessed from a function. You must explicitly do something like `global $con;` inside the function `GetData()` before you try to access `$con`.

From a system design point of view this isn't the best approach. It will make it hard to keep track of your variables. You won't know who (which part of your script) is accessing that global and you won't know how it is being modified or in what order. This can lead to some bugs that are very difficult to identify.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . auth.php;
```

**Require_once** or **require** with Unix full path works like a charm. Replace **include** stroke in your code.